# Nginx redirect rule to show /index.html for any missing page, but maintain url

Tags: nginx

If someone goes to mysite.com/notafile and it doesn't actually exist, I'd like to show mysite.com instead. However, I want to maintain the url in the user's browser, so it still shows mysite.com/notafile.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you have a working Nginx configuration?

Answer (score 0):

When a file doesn't exits, web-server throws `404 Not Found` error.
What you are asking can be simply achieved by defining a custom 404 page which in your case can be an index.html page. Add this to your nginx config:

```
error_page 404 /index.html;
```

So in this case, the `mysite.com/notafile` URL will show the `index.html` page but also maintain the URL in the browser. However it is not a redirect, it simply displays index.html in place of error page.